# Invoking a lightning component using a button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, controller, case

Is there a way to invoke a lightning component by clicking a button? lets say I have created a reusable Case creation Component which i want to call on click of a button called "Open a Case"

It only lets me to call a controller and but not the component directly, please suggest

Comment: You can add the Lightning component inside an VF page and invoke that VF page using the button.

Comment: I am not using VF pages as its for standalone app for lightning out. I called a controller and used Aura if to display the component but i am not sue if thats the only way or its just a workaround. any additional info will help

Comment: Got this working through dynamically creating components on click of a UI button. tried events, it did work but I found this as an easy and a cleaner option.

Comment: Add your solution as an Answer to this submission, so that it can help others.

Answer (score 1):

Got this working through dynamically creating components on click of a UI button. tried events, it did work but I found this as an easy and a cleaner option.

```
loadComp: function(component, event, helper) 
    {
        $A.createComponents([
            ["<namespace:Your component>",{}]],
            function(components, status){
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    component.set("v.body", components[0]);
                }
            }
```